# how to increase the Bitmap font in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I created a Bitmap font but I don't seem to be able to increase the size of the text. Take a look at my code. font.draw(batch, "Score : " + highscore, 10, 300);.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapFont` has [`BitmapFont.setScale(float)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#setScale-float-) where you can for example set it to `2.0f` to increase the size to 200%.

However this is probably not want you want to do, because it will result in pretty bad quality.

What you should do is either use [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) to create several versions of your font, with different font sizes and switch them in code.

Another alternative would be to use the [gdx-freetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) extension (which is not available on all platforms though) and generate the fonts in the size you need them at runtime.

Comment: Is their another way to do it? (that support all platforms)

Comment: Not really. You might use very big font sizes and then downscale them, as it will result in better quality, but it will still not be optimal.